# Why Does Empty MySQL Database Claim to Have Duplicates (Python 3)?

Tags: python, mysql

So I have a quick function that's supposed to upload data (stored in a Python dictionary) to a MySQL database.

```
def uploadData(of_item):
    global DB_HOST
    global DB_USER
    global DB_PASSWORD
    global DB_DATABASE
    my_db = connector.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, database=DB_DATABASE, port=3306)
    my_db.autocommit = True
    my_cursor = my_db.cursor()
    print("\rThe DB pipeline is now connected.")
    slots_text = ", ".join([a[0] for a in of_item.items()])
    values_text = ", ".join(["'" + a[1].replace("'", "\\'") + "'" for a in of_item.items()])
    set_portion_text = ", ".join([a[0] + " = " + "'" + a[1].replace("'", "\\'") + "'" for a in of_item.items()])
    sql = 'INSERT INTO UsersData ({0}) VALUES ({1})'.format(slots_text, values_text)
    try:
        my_cursor.execute(sql)
        row_cnt = my_cursor.rowcount
        my_db.commit()
        my_cursor.close()
        my_db.close()
        print("\r" + str(row_cnt) + " is now in UsersData.")
        return [True, str(row_cnt)]
    except Exception as exception:
        print("\n".join(["The update failed for profileID: " + of_item['UniqueId'],
                         str(exception),
                         str(sql),
                         "*",
                         'Item:',
                         str(of_item),
                         "*"]))
        my_cursor.close()
        my_db.close()
        return [False, 0]
```

Currently, the `row_cnt` sits at -1, so it should be entirely empty. However, when I execute the function, I'm constantly getting this thrown error:

> 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-123' for key 'profileId_2'

Now, profileId_2 is just this:

```
...
  UNIQUE KEY `profileId_2` (`profileId`,`companyId`),
...
```

`profileId` is whatever the user's unique ID is, and `companyId` is just a preset (in this case, 123). It's odd that there would be a claimed duplicate, since there's nothing in the database yet.

First, what might be causing this error? Second, how can I get through it and successfully append new entries to UsersData?

Comment: `row_cnt` is the number of rows that were inserted by the last query, not the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Don't use string substitution into queries, use placeholders and give the values as the second argument to `my_cursor.execute()`

Comment: Oh, I see. Then is there a cursor method that allows me to know the number of rows in the entire table?

Comment: No, use a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UsersData`